# Interpolation along stream network (QGIS, GRASS, PostGIS, R..)

Tags: r, networking, stream, interpolation, extrapolation

I would like to inter/extrapolate values(concentration) along a stream network line. So far theoretically the best match would be **rtop** package in R, but somehow there is a bug and I cannot execute the example data. Do anyone has any other "ready" suggestion using any kind of OS program?

However, I tried to solve the problem in R, but I came a cross several problems.
My dataframe ( I have also shapefiles, stream network, catchments areas)
**StartID** | **EndID** | **Discharge** | **Length** | **Value**

First of all I would like to have inverse distance weighted interpolation (**IDW**), so to find the segments where I have observations and interpolate between the observations for the NA values depending on their distance between the observations.
Secondly I also would like to consider the discharge. When 2 streams join, the stream with higher discharge should have more influence on the concentration in the next segment.

I am able to look for NA values and check if there is observations upstream or downstream of the segment and weighted by discharge and take the mean:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(DF)) {
if(is.na(DF[i,c("Value")]))
{ a<-merge(DF[i,], DF, by.x=c("StartID"),by.y=c("EndID"), x.all)
a<-a[complete.cases(a[,8]),]
b<-merge(DF[i,], DF, by.x=c("EndID"),by.y=c("StartID"), x.all)
b<-b[complete.cases(b[,8]),]
DF[i,c("Value")] <- mean((sum(a[,c("Discharge.y")]*a[,c("Value.y")])/sum(a[,c("Discharge.y")])),(sum(b[,c("Discharge.y")]*b[,c("Values.y")])/sum(b[,c("Discharge.y")])), na.rm=TRUE, trim=0)
```

But I think it would be better to look for the observations close to each other and interpolate for the NA values. But I really got stuck. I do not hope for ready-to-use-scripts, but I would be glad if I could get some feedback and directions.

Thanks a lot, Celia

Comment: You probably want to look into the `igraph` package in R, and to build a directed graph from your line shapefile with length as an edge attribute.

Comment: You could also ask a question regarding your problem with `rtop`, and see if you can get that fixed.

Comment: See also: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SSN/index.html

Comment: @Spacedman: +1 for SSN. But AFAIK SSN needs the ArcGIS toolbox 'stars' to prepare the data. I would be happy, if I am wrong ;)

Comment: @Spacedman: Thanks, I spent some time on igraph, but I could not find solution for finding closest observations. It could work perfectly for one-direction (from upstream to downstream, or from downstream to upstream). But it is not exactly what I want.

Comment: @EDi, unfortunately, I do not have access to ArcGIS )-:

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra: Thanks, I will try. So I tried to execute the netProp example. (One minor thing the stream network shapefile called riverNetwork, instead of rnet). 'rnet$pred = 
+     pred$var1.pred[match(rnet$TOJCT, pred$JCTID)]
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, name, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 306' That I could still solve it it was just false column names (rnet$OBJECTID and pred$IS). However, I am missing the to and from columns definitely.